# A script to call /opt/myfolder/myscript

Tags: 12.04, server, scripts

I am try to have it when I log into the server that all I have to do is type start myscript from the location of /opt/myfolderofscripts/myscripts and also have it say starting script.

I don't want to move my scripts. The scripts call all of the other scripts in that folder so I can't really move this script.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write another script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# go your script's directory
cd /path/to/script/

# launch your script
run_your_script.sh
```

If you want it to be executed on each startup, assign the new script to user root and put it in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Yes you can. Even cooler: try notify-send "starting script"

Comment: Would I be able to put it in the usr/local/bin or is that not a good place to put it.  Thanks

Comment: You can place your script nearly anywhere, even in your home directory or on the desktop.

Comment: So would it be echo try notify-send "starting script" or echo "starting script" notify-send? Thanks

Comment: just: notify-send "any text"